# Is there a way to use the or operator in PHP like in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, operator-keyword

I want to get a other property of a associative array when the first one doesn't exist.

JavaScript:

```
var obj = {"a": "123", "b": "456"};
var test = obj.a || obj.b;
console.log(test);
```

Is it possible to do this in PHP:

```
$arr = array("a" => "123", "b" => "456");
$test = $arr["a"] || $arr["b"];
echo $test;
```

When I run the PHP, I get 1.

Is there any *short* way I could do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PHP you can do

```
//Check if $arr["a"] exists, and assign if it does, or assign $arr["b"] else
$arr = array("a" => "123", "b" => "456");
$test = isset($arr["a"]) ? $arr["a"] : $arr["b"];
```

But within PHP 7, you can do

```
//Does the same as above, but available only from PHP 7
$arr = array("a" => "123", "b" => "456");
$test = $arr["a"] ?? $arr["b"];
```

See [operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Note that `$arr["a"] || $arr["b"]` in PHP compute the boolean value only.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Your welcome! I think the second form is a nice improvement of PHP7! :)

Comment: note that in PHP the `??` operator is **null** coalescing, while in JS `||` is **falsy** coalescing; so `false || 'a'` in JS does not translate to `false ?? 'a'` in PHP (which evaluates to `false`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this variant:

```
$arr = array("a" => "123", "b" => "456");
$test = isset($arr['a']) ? $arr['a'] : $arr['b'];
echo $test;
```

[Ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)